# CheckedListBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, infragistics, checkedlistbox

We are working on an application using the **MVVM** architectural style (**WPF**) and facing an issue.
Before using **WPF** we have worked with **WinForms** and we used **CheckedListBox**. But now we are unable to find such control in **WPF**.
We are also using **Infragistic** toolkit.

Please provide any kind of help. Any lead will be appreciable.[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can take a Listbox and give it a Template with a Checkbox in.
Something like:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

This looks like this:

[image: Checklistbox in WPF]

Edit: The Items must have a Property "IsSelected" or you have to Wrap them in a SelectableItem helper class, which holds the original Item and a IsSelected Property.